# Command is not defined? (trying to make a discord bot with random responses)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that gives random responses if you type in a command, and I'm not doing so good: it says command not defined?

Here's the code:

```
const PREFIX = 'ly?';
if (command === 'topic') {
  function randomMessage() {
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 2); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 0:
        return 'Helfdlo!';
      case 1:
        return 'Byfde!';
      case 2:
        return 'Ranfddom';
      case 3:
        return 'Hefdllo!';
      case 4:
        return 'Bfdye!';
      case 5:
        return 'Ranfddom';
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if(command === 'topic')
```

command is not pre defined. You have to do it yourself. Add this code right below your PREFIX = 'ly?';

```
  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

That should do it.

And, Math.round(Math.random()*2) does **not** output a number between 0-5, it outputs a number between 0-2. If you want numbers between 0-5 use either "Math.round(Math.random()*5)" or Math.floor"Math.random()*6"